# How can I place functions in a set in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'd like make a Set module containing functions. But there seems to be no way to compare functions, which Set needs. This obvious-looking thing compiles:

```ml
module Action = struct
  type t = unit -> unit
  let compare : t -> t -> int = Stdlib.compare
end
module Actions = Set.Make(Action)
```

But if I attempt to use it:

`Fatal error: exception Invalid_argument("compare: functional value")`

I just want compare that the functions are the same object, I am not  trying to do something silly like compare them for equal behaviour.

Am I supposed to use something from the Obj module here?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you trying to implement an `Ordered Set`?

Comment: No, I was trying to implement a priority queue of functions to call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The semantics of `Stdlib.compare` is to look arbitrarily deep inside the objects to see how their subparts compare. This doesn't really work for functions, as you point out. So OCaml doesn't allow `compare` to be applied to functions.

There isn't really a useful order that can be applied to functions, even if you're willing to use physical equality. Function values are immutable and can be duplicated or moved physically by the runtime system, at least in theory.

Since the ordering would necessarily be arbitrary, you can get the same effect by making your own arbitrary order: pair the functions with an int value that increases monotonically as you create new pairs.

Answer (score 6):

Add an identity to your actions, e.g., you can compare actions by name,

```
module Action = struct 

  type t = {
    name : string;
    func : (unit -> unit);
  }

  let compare x y = String.compare x.name y.name
 end
```

You should also ensure that all actions have different names, for example by introducing a global hash table that records all created actions. Make sure that actions are only creatable via the `Action` module, by adding an appropriate signature.

Answer (score 2):

OCaml [Stdlib](https://ocaml.org/api/Stdlib.html) `compare` documentation states ...

> ***`val compare : 'a -> 'a -> int`***

> `compare x y` returns 0 if x is equal to y, a negative integer if x is less than y, and a positive integer if x is greater than y. The ordering implemented by `compare` is compatible with the comparison predicates `=`, `<` and `>` defined above, with one difference on the treatment of the float value **`nan`**. Namely, the comparison predicates treat **`nan`** as different from any other float value, including itself; while `compare` treats **`nan`** as equal to itself and less than any other float value. This treatment of **`nan`** ensures that compare defines a total ordering relation.

> ***`compare` applied to functional values may raise Invalid_argument***. `compare` applied to cyclic structures may not terminate.

> The `compare` function can be used as the comparison function required by the `Set.Make` and `Map.Make` functors, as well as the `List.sort` and `Array.sort` functions.

Now we have two notion(s) of equality in OCaml, namely...

1. ***`Structural Equality`***: Expressed using operator `=`, the type of which is

```ocaml
# (=);;
- : 'a -> 'a -> bool = <fun>
```

2. ***`Physical Equality`***: Expressed using operator `==`, the type of which is

```ocaml
# (==);;
- : 'a -> 'a -> bool = <fun>
```

As we can see, the type of both is same, but the `function application` of both of them is different when it comes to `function value` as arguments.

***`Structural Equality` doesn't hold over function values, but `Physical Equality` may.*** Trying to compare(as in `=`) with `function values` throws. And as stated in the documentation of `Stdlib.compare`, it uses `structural equality`.

---

### ***Illustration: Structural Equality with Function Values***

```ocaml
# let f x = x;;
val f : 'a -> 'a = <fun>
# let g x = x;;
val g : 'a -> 'a = <fun>
# f = g;;
Exception: Invalid_argument "compare: functional value".
# g = f;;
Exception: Invalid_argument "compare: functional value".
```

---

### ***Illustration: Physical Equality with Function Values***

```ocaml
# let f x = x;;
val f : 'a -> 'a = <fun>
# let g x = x;;
val g : 'a -> 'a = <fun>
# f == g;;
- : bool = false
# f == f;;
- : bool = true
# g == g;;
- : bool = true
# g == f;;
- : bool = false
# let h x y = x + y;;
val h : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# h == f;;
Error: This expression has type int -> int
       but an expression was expected of type int -> int -> int
       Type int is not compatible with type int -> int
```

So in short, I don't think we can use `Stdlib.compare` with `Set.Make` with `function values`.

So ...

1. Either, we will have to keep the `type t` in `Action` module to something over which `structural equality` can be applied if we have to continue using `Stdlib.compare`.
2. Or, implement `compare` of your own so that it can do something with those `function values` as arguments, along with satisfying the function contract of `val compare : t -> t -> int` as mandated by [Set.OrderedType](https://ocaml.org/api/Set.OrderedType.html) module type.

---

---

***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***